# Download all S3 files uploaded within a given time period

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I would like to all files uploaded to an S3 button within a given time period.
For all example, everything that was uploaded between 05-11-2017 and 07-11-2018.

Please note that due to the size of the bucket downloading the entire bucket is not an option.

Comment: What platform are you on? What tools do you have available?

Comment: From the AWS console